# In what context can the method described below be of use? Can anyone provide some useful example?

Tags: swift

I found the following method in a part of a source code, and I can't understand the difference between `Self.Type` and `Self.Type.Type`

```
property SomeProperty {
    static func type() -> Self.Type.Type {
        return self.dynamicType
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can give me some insights?

---

The snippet above comes from the following extension:

```
extension Property {
    static func size() -> Int {
        return Int(ceil(Double(sizeof(self))/Double(sizeof(Int))))
    }

    static func type() -> Self.Type.Type { return self.dynamicType }

    mutating func codeInto(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) { 
        (UnsafeMutablePointer(pointer) as
            UnsafeMutablePointer<Self>).memory = self
    }

    mutating func codeOptionalInto(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) { 
        (UnsafeMutablePointer(pointer) as
            UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<Self>>).memory = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post more of your code. It's difficult to help with these small snippets.

Comment: This is full property description

extension Property {
    
    static func size() -> Int {
        return Int(ceil(Double(sizeof(self))/Double(sizeof(Int))))
    }
    
    static func type() -> Self.Type.Type {
        return self.dynamicType
    }
    
    mutating func codeInto(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) {
        (UnsafeMutablePointer(pointer) as UnsafeMutablePointer<Self>).memory = self
    }
    
    mutating func codeOptionalInto(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) {
        (UnsafeMutablePointer(pointer) as UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<Self>>).memory = self
    }

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the original author misunderstood how `static` works with `self` and subclasses. They probably originally wrote this, intending to return "the type of this particular subclass:"

```
protocol TypeReturning {}

extension TypeReturning {
    static func type() -> Self.Type {
        return self.dynamicType
    }
}
```

The mistake was that `dynamicType` isn't really meaningful here. Because of the `static` context, `self` *is* the dynamic type. But the author would have received the error:

> error: cannot convert return expression of type 'Self.Type.Type' to return type 'Self.Type'

I assume they read that error and thought "ah! I got my return type wrong" and they fixed it:

```
static func type() -> Self.Type.Type {
    return self.dynamicType
}
```

The correct solution would have been:

```
static func type() -> Self.Type {
    return self
}
```

Though the better solution would have likely been to avoid this entirely; it's an unnecessary function. They just mean `SomeClass.self` and should write it that way.

`.Type.Type` is meaningful. It's a metatype (the type of the type itself). But I'm not aware of anything you could actually do with it. Types are not first-class objects in Swift.